# Tabbed Google Maps V3 Info-Window with mini-map AND content

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm wondering how I can load an InfoWindow with two tabs: one displaying a minimap more zoomed in on wherever the infowindow is, like the marker.showMapBlowup();  of V2.

The other tab would be regular text content I've created.

Anyone know how to do this in V3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of googling around : http://reizigers.jade1.nl/Tabbed_Infowindows.html

good luck